# react-testing-library doesn't render all parts of a VirtualTable

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, react-testing-library

[CodeSandbox with Unit Tests](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-leakey-zbws7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&previewwindow=tests&theme=dark)

The CodeSandbox above contains a small code segment that shows the problem. The rendered table contains a bit of data. Everything on the left side is rendered and around the center, `@testing-library/react` stops rendering anything.

Visually, everything is fine. But the HTML rendered by `@testing-library/react` misses the entire right half of the table.

You can even see this if you hard reload the tab with CodeSandbox in it, then navigate to the "Browser" tab. The right half will be missing. Click the Browser refresh button in CodeSandbox and everything will be rendered just fine.

Without `VirtualTable`, everything renders perfectly. However, I need `VirtualTable` for performance reasons.

Extending the viewport programmatically doesn't help.

```js
// setupTests.js
global.resizeWindow = (x, y) => {
    window.innerWidth = x
    window.innerHeight = y
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
}

// In the test
global.resizeWindow(4096, 2160)
// Same result, no change
```

Is there any way to keep the benefits of VirtualTable while still running tests on the data contained on the right side of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the response from DevExpress:

> Hi,
>
> Thank you for your sample. I have discussed this behavior with our
>   developers and we concluded that this is the expected behavior. The
>   VirtualTable plugin renders only visual parts of the Grid control. So,
>   we recommend that you use the Table plugin for tests and the
>   VirtualTable plugin in a real application.
>
> Thanks, Alessandro

So it would appear that since we don't have a real browser, the VirtualTable sees no need to render anything.

The solution would be to render a regular Table in a testing scenario, and a VirtualTable in a real-world scenario.

```js
function areWeTestingWithJest() {
    return process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID !== undefined;
}
```

However, using testing code in production code is usually considered bad practice, so I'll just avoid testing VirtualTables and test the data in other places instead.